# How to set alarm when I reach destination?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am implementing location alarm demo, and I successfully getting notification when I reach my destination. But I want to use alarm instead of simple notification, I don't know about alarm service and till now I haven't implemented it.

Here is my code of getting notification:

```
public class AreWeThereIntentService extends IntentService {
    private final String TAG = AreWeThereIntentService.class.getName();
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private Gson gson;
    public AreWeThereIntentService() {
        super("AreWeThereIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.SharedPrefs.Geofences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        gson = new Gson();
        // 1. Get the event
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (event != null) {
            if (event.hasError()) {
                onError(event.getErrorCode());
            } else {
                // 2. Get the transition type
                int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();
                if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                        transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL ||
                        transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                    List<String> geofenceIds = new ArrayList<>();
                    // 3. Accumulate a list of event geofences
                    for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
                        geofenceIds.add(geofence.getRequestId());
                    }
                    if (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                            transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {
                        // 4. Pass the geofence list to the notification method
                        onEnteredGeofences(geofenceIds);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void onEnteredGeofences(List<String> geofenceIds) {

        // 1. Outer loop over all geofenceIds
        for (String geofenceId : geofenceIds) {
            String geofenceName = "";
            // 2, Loop over all geofence keys in prefs and retrieve NamedGeofence from SharedPreferences
            Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
                String jsonString = prefs.getString(entry.getKey(), null);
                NamedGeofence namedGeofence = gson.fromJson(jsonString, NamedGeofence.class);
                if (namedGeofence.id.equals(geofenceId)) {
                    geofenceName = namedGeofence.name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // 3. Set the notification text and send the notification
            String contextText =
                    String.format(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Text), geofenceName);
            // 1. Create a NotificationManager
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            long[] pattern = {0, 100, 200, 300};
            // 3. Create and send a notification
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.map_marker_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Title))
                    .setContentText(contextText)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contextText))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setVibrate(pattern)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    }

    private void onError(int i) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Geofencing Error: " + i);
    }
}
```

What I want is alarm instead of simple notification when I enter Geofence.

Comment: Can you please try to implement an alarm (without geofence) on your own first? That should be enough to answer your own question.

Comment: Mate, your question refers to "how to set alarm".

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i will implement if no one answer my question.

Comment: As per [asking good StackOverflow questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), research is the top suggestion. Even trying it on your own is recommended, so you should do that before asking on StackOverflow and ask questions with problems with about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i got your question right ... use alarm manager for alarm and send notification through broadcast receiver like this...

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1, pendingIntent);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, randomValue, 0,pendingIntent);
```

and in AlarmReceiver

```
public class Silent_notification_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Alert")
                .setContentText("You are in Silent Area");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there if you want behaviour like alarm or phone call, you need to wake your application open activity/fragment/dialog and play ringtone.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html

Comment: can u give me a little demo about what you talking

Comment: after some googling found this might possible useful http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-ringtone-and-ringtonemanager-example-get-default-and-current-ringtone have not tested.